# why is logged_out.html not overriding in django registration?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using built-in django login and logout. In my Project/urls.py i have added url's for both login and logout.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from account import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='Index'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$',auth_views.login,name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$',auth_views.logout,name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$',views.register,name='register'),
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$',views.profile,name='profile'),    
]
```

and i've templates folder inside my account app folder. i have directory structure like this

```
account
   -templates
      -registration
          -login.html
          -logged_out.html
          -register.html
      -rest_html_files
-rest files
```

i've read django docs which say that for login() default template is registration/login.html which is working fine in my project and logout() default template is registration/logged_out.html if no arguments is supplied but whenever it Logout button ( which has a  href={% url 'logout' %} ) is clicked it redirects to the admin logout page rather than my custom logout page. 
what could possibly be wrong??

Comment: Could you post the code for the view?

Comment: view does not have to do anything in this case as i am using django auth.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `django.contrib.admin` app also has a `registration/logged_out.html` template.

To ensure that the template from your 'account' app, is used, make sure it is **above** 'django.contrib.admin' in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'account',
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
)
```

The app template loader goes through the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and each app's template directory until it finds a match. Therefore, if admin is above your app, then Django will use the template from the admin instead of from your app.

Comment: thanks for answer @Alasdair but i've smashed my head hours before asking the question and my app is there in Installed apps. To your comment i already know the next_page attribute all i wanted to ask is why, if login is overrided then why logout is not working the same way.

Comment: Having your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` is not enough. It needs to be **above** 'django.contrib.admin'. Your login template is currently used because the admin app doesn't have a `registration/login.html` template.

Comment: thanks !!!that did the trick.sorry that i didn't understand earlier and sorry, they are not letting me upvote your answer..;-)

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't worry about the upvote, you'll be able to vote on answers once you have a little more reputation.

Comment: This is a huge Gotcha! for django newbies like myself. I broke my head for hours and then realized that I had my custom app last on the list. Wondering where best the django docs could warn about this behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can set to redirect it to a next page like this:

```
url(r'^accounts/logout/$',auth_views.logout, name='logout', 
                           {'next_page': '/path_to_your_page/'})
```

According to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout

Or

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next=/path_to_the_page"> Logout</a>
```

Comment: thanks kushtrimh! but i had already figured that out. All i am asking is what could be probable cause this method is not working as it should be.