# when I logout the app goes into a loop a 203 http status

Tags: python, django, routes, django-templates

I´m doing an exercise that involves user authentication. Everything works smooth, but when I log out the app goes into a loop with this message on the console:

```
[04/Apr/2018 22:44:14] "GET /account/logged_out/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Apr/2018 22:44:14] "GET /account/logged_out/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/Apr/2018 22:44:14] "GET /account/logged_out/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb3gD.png)

**At the end of the *settings.py* file**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account:login')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:logout')
```

**The *urls.py* file**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    # path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

    # login / logout urls
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logged_out.html'), name='logout'),
```

**The *views.py* file**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

**The *base.html* template**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/base.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <ul class="menu">
                <li> {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="{% url "account:dashboard" %}">My dashboard</a></li>
                <li> {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}<a href="#">Images</a></li>
                <li> {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}<a href="#">People</a></li>
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="user">
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                Hello {{ request.user.first_name }}, <a href="{% url "account:logout %}">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url "account:dashboard" %}"></a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My guess is that the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL is redirecting continuously after the logout to the logout url and LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL does his thing again and again.

What is the most correct way to handle this situation?

I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you say: `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:logout')` is saying you want to redirect to the `logout` view. You should change this setting to some other view, e.g. the login view:

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:login')
```

If you want to display the default Django `logged_out.html` template, you should not redirect, it's what the logout view renders by default (i.e. remove `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`) from your settings.

If you want to display your own custom template, either override Django's `registration/logged_out.html` template in one of your template directories (again, remove `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` from settings), or create your own `TemplateView` for this and redirect to this new view you create.

Comment: Hi dirkgroten, your solution works indeed, but it's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I'd like to render the logged_out.html template in order to display a logged out confirmation to the user. How would be the most correct way of approaching this situation?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Even having the template in "templates/registration/logged_out.html" it wasn't being overridden because in the setting.py file, inside the INSTALLED_APPS list, I had to place my app on top of Django default apps. Then it worked :)

Thanks a lot, you helped me out a lot, you put me on track to find this post which had the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153108/why-is-logged-out-html-not-overriding-in-django-registration
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

LOGIN_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL accept named URL patterns. That means you only have to write the URL name in the setrings.
This should fix your error.

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'  # url name
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'logout'
```

Comment: correct, but reverse_lazy is not what's causing the redirect loop. What is, is redirecting to 'account:logout' when logging out...

Comment: Hi Xhens, your solution throws this error:
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[04/Apr/2018 23:44:09] "GET /account/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 105445

Answer (score 0):

You must redirect to the login after the logout:

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:login')
```

What you can do also is to add some query parameters to personalise the login with a message just after the logout.

Use a function like this one:

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode

def my_reverse(viewname, kwargs=None, query_kwargs=None):
    """
    Custom reverse to add a query string after the url
    Example usage:
    url = my_reverse('my_test_url', kwargs={'pk': object.id}, query_kwargs={'next': reverse('home')})
    """
    url = reverse(viewname, kwargs=kwargs)

    if query_kwargs:
        return u'%s?%s' % (url, urlencode(query_kwargs))

    return url
```

Then you can do

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = my_reverse("account:login", query_kwargs={'logoutMessage': True})
```

in your login view you can get the query parameter and add a message in the context to render in the template

Comment: Wow, looks pro, I'll try to implement your solution. Thanks Karim!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the order of the INSTALLED_APPS list in the settings.py. My app should be on top of Django's default Apps. Now Django's original logged_out.html template is being overridden.

Here the post with the original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157729/6329996

Here The INSTALLED_APPS list working:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My Apps
    'account',

    # Django Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```