# Custom logout page not landing

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication

### On clicking logout button the custom landing page is not landing,but the default django-admin page is landing!

hey! I am trying to learn django from the book django2 by example so i created a dashboard page which is having a logout button but on clicking the button it shows the django-admin landing page and not the one I created !

urls.py(main-project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('account.urls')),
]
```

urls.py(account-app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views



urlpatterns = [
                # post views
                
                path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
                path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='log_out'),
                path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
                # change password urls
                path('password_change/',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),
                                        name='password_change'),
                path('password_change/done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(),
                                            name='password_change_done'),
            ]
```

It should show this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWHe2.png) but apparantely it's showing the django-admin default logout page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqKYk.png)

logged_out.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    
    
    {% block title %}Logged out{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    <h1>Logged out</h1>
    <p>You have been successfully logged out. You can <a href="{% url
    "login" %}">log-in again</a>.</p>
    {% endblock %}
```

**update**- got the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is logged\_out.html not overriding in django registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153108/why-is-logged-out-html-not-overriding-in-django-registration)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I got the solution, I just have to mention my application before the **django.contrib.admin** as both of the app and default admin shares the same urls and views. So in order to view mine custom pages I have to change the settings in the **INSTALLED_APPS** as per the above settings..